# when to use Word2Vec over LSTM?

Tags: neural-network, lstm, word2vec

I'm trying to decide on a language training model for my code. and I wanted to know what aspects and elements should I take into consideration before picking one of them?
I understand that for larger data it is preferred to use an LSTM model, but what about Word2Vec? when it's better to choose it over the LSTM model?
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use pretrained word2vec to get the word vector of your sentences and the you can perform max or mean of those word vectors to get the sentence vector and then apply any ML model to classifier. This is very baseline model but gives some good results too. Please check [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.09843.pdf) paper and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01759.pdf) paper.
2. You can use pretrained Word vectors as initial weight vectors of words in LSTM architecture and train the LSTM model.